# Lighttpd 403 error

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I have 2 servers one running on cenotos 5.9 and centos 6.3.i am trying to configure centos 6.3 as a static file server.when i installed lighttpd on centos 6.3 with server document root in /srv/www/lighttpd.i am able to run index.html file and and other html file within the same directory.if put html file in new directory as new/s.html i am getting 403 forbidden error

- /srv/www/lighttpd/s.html -- works fine
- /srv/www/lighttpd/new/s.html --403 error

all the file have 777 permission

PS if I replicate the procss in centos 5.9  everything works fine

Comment: what's the `chown` and `chmod` of the *folders*?

Comment: the permissions for the folders are 777 full read write and edit

Comment: I also believe its is a permission error.the owner is the root(admin) user.i dont have the access to root user.